# Enabling MIDI editors to play MIDI files on Linux (without an external musical device)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, midi

I cannot enable MIDI files to be played on Linux in editors such as [Qtractor](https://www.qtractor.org/qtractor-downloads.html#Downloads) or [MidiEditor](http://www.midieditor.org/index.php?category=download). Why is it not working when [VLC](https://wiki.videolan.org/Midi/) can play these MIDI files?

**Details:**

I was able to make [VLC](https://wiki.videolan.org/Midi/) play `.mid` files on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS by installing:

```
sudo apt-get install fluid-soundfont-gm fluid-soundfont-gs
sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-fluidsynth
```

However, I am not able to make them play on some MIDI editors like  [MidiEditor](http://www.midieditor.org/index.php?category=download) and [Qtractor](https://www.qtractor.org/qtractor-downloads.html#Downloads). The problem is always the same - It cannot find the MIDI output device. I do not want to use any external hardware output device. Instead, I wish to use the software synthesizer (fluidsynth) in the same way as VLC uses it.

For example, with Qtractor I got [this error](https://www.rncbc.org/drupal/node/1976)

```
The audio/MIDI engine could not be initialized. Make sure the JACK audio server (jackd) and/or the ALSA Sequencer kernel module (snd-seq-midi) are up and running and then restart the session.
```

I was trying to solve it by installing `qsynth` or `qjackctl` as described [here](http://tedfelix.com/linux/linux-midi.html#qsynth). But for some reason I don't understand I cannot. Terminal output:

```
myComputer:~/SW$ sudo apt install qsynth

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 midieditor : Depends: qtbase5-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: qtdeclarative5-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt5webkit5-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libsqlite3-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: qt5-default but it is not installable
              Depends: qtmultimedia5-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: qttools5-dev-tools
              Depends: libqt5multimedia5-plugins but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: gstreamer1.0-doc but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found a solution. Maybe it will be helpful for somebody facing similar problems:

- This problem: `You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these. The following packages have unmet dependencies:` was caused by broken `MidiEditor` package, when I uninstalled it `apt` started to work properly
- Then I installed `sudo apt-get install fluidsynth` which installed `qsynth` also.
- I realized that `qsynth` complains that the `JACK` server is not working
- So I installed `sudo apt install qjackctl`

  - it asked me for permission, to give it *real-time* kernel rights. Not sure what that is, but I complied.
- Qtractor now does not complain, but I was still not getting any sound (MIDI seems to play but silently)
- So I was looking at the Qsynth `Setup...` button and found that the `Soundfonts` tab is empty. So I added some `.sf2` file there using the `Open...` button
- I restarted Qtractor and now it pays the MIDI-file just fine

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/771353/what-package-to-install-to-play-midi-files-in-ubuntu-16-04/771365#771365